# how to implement tent activation function in pytorch?

Tags: torch, activation-function, triangular

I need to create tent activation function as it is shown in the following image. 
I was wondering if there is torch built-in tent activation function? 
If not, is there any way to create this activation function?

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think this can be used.

```
y = (x>0)*(1-x>0)*(1-x) + (x<0)*(1+x>0)*(1+x)
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution but I think your solution can not handle the batch data.

Answer (score 0):

I found simple solution to implement the tent activation function in forward function

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
class Net(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
         super(Net, self).__init__()

    def forward(self, input):
        out = nn.functional.relu(input + 1) - 2 * nn.functional.relu(input) + nn.functional.relu(input - 1)
        return out
```

same solution could be implemented using

```
nn.ReLU()
```

as the layers of network.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
torch.maximum(1 - x.abs(), 0)
```